# Show message on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to show a message when someone clicks on a checkbox.

Do you have any idea to display a message?
I tried, but it doesn't work.

The Checkbox :

```
echo '<div><input type="checkbox" value="' . $products_id .'" id="productsCompare" title="Compare" /> Compare</div>';
```

the script including the element to show a message

```
     <script>
       $(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){   
            var chkArray = [];   
            $('#container').html('');

            //put the selected checkboxes values in chkArray[]
            $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
                chkArray.push($(this).val());
            });

// message
            var toggle = false;
            $('#productsCompare').click(function() {
              $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',!toggle);
              toggle = !toggle;
               $(\'productsCompare\').show();
            });



            //If chkArray is not empty show the <div> and create the list
              if(chkArray.length !== 0){      
                  $.ajax({
                          method: 'POST',
                          url : "http://localhost/.........test.php",
                          data : {product_id: chkArray},
                      });  
              }

        });
    })
    </script>
```

The message

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="productsCompare" style="display:none;">
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="alert alert-info text-md-center">
    <span class="text-md-center">
      <button class="btn"><a href="compare.php">Compare</a></button>
    </span>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to do the display?  I see you clear #container, but I don't see you ever populating it.

Comment: `$(\'.Compare\')` Is an error though, remove the slashes.  And `id="Compare"` is an id, not a class, if that is what you are trying to target, so you need to use `#` instead

Comment: @Taplar; I just want to try to display the message when someone click on a checkbox.

Comment: @Chris, can you provide a minimal code that shows what you are trying to do? It seems that the `$('#container').html('');` and all the ajax stuff is irrelevant to your current problem. Is that right?
Also, I see that you have two elements in the DOM with the same id: both your checkbox and your hidden _div_ have an id of _productsCompare_. ids should be unique in your document!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my example and try to modify it with your case.

```js
$("#box").addClass('novis');
$("#ch").on('click',function(){
 $("#box").toggleClass('novis','vis');
});
```

```css
.vis{ display: block; }
.novis{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Show</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch" unchecked>

 <div id="box">
  <p>Hello world</p>
 </div>
```